# how to get the children inside of an i tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been having trouble trying to  get the children inside of an i tag I have tried many ways and read many questions on StackOverflow but still no help.

Here is my code:

```
function markAsRead() { //marked as read function    
  console.log($(this).children(".gsdfs").text());
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<i class='fas fa-times' style='color: #FFCC00; cursor: pointer;margin-left: 87%; margin-top: -53px; position: absolute; ' onclick='markAsRead()'>
    <input type='hidden' value='123456787' class='notification_trackId'>
    <p style='color: transparent;' class='gsdfs'>Hello World</p>
</i>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that inside the function.

**Please Note:** I have change the style `margin-top: -53px` and `color: transparent` so that the element is view-able in the code snippet.

```js
function markAsRead(el) { //marked as read function
  console.log($(el).children(".gsdfs").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class='fas fa-times' style='color: #FFCC00; cursor: pointer;margin-left: 87%; margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; ' onclick='markAsRead(this)'>
  <input type='hidden' value='123456787' class='notification_trackId'>
  <p style='color: black;' class='gsdfs'>Hello World</p>
</i>
```

If the element with class `gsdfs` is nested inside some other element you have to use `find()`:

```js
function markAsRead(el) { //marked as read function
  console.log($(el).find(".gsdfs").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class='fas fa-times' style='color: #FFCC00; cursor: pointer;margin-left: 87%; margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; ' onclick='markAsRead(this)'>
  <input type='hidden' value='123456787' class='notification_trackId'>
  <div>
    <p style='color: black;' class='gsdfs'>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</i>
```

Comment: Just a word of caution here, `children()` checks only immediate child elements which works in this case but if your `.gsdfs` is nested inside another element use `find()`.

Comment: @kiranvj, you are right....I have updated the answer by adding that as part of the answer..... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate children, you can use `each`:

```
const parentSelector = ...;
$(parentSelector).children(".gsdfs").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text()); // $(this) is every child.
});
```

But you don't need it..

You want to get the text of `gsdfs`.
This element is `p` element with class: `gsdfs`.

So you need to do:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('gsdfs')[0].textContent);
```

OR

```
console.log($('.gsdfs').text())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this).find(".gsdfs")` will return an array of child elements inside current element having class name gsdfs. if you want to itrate the use the followong code:

```
$.each($(this).find(".gsdfs"),function(index,element){
console.log(element);
});
```

In order to get html elements in side current element, you can use `.html()` function of JQuery like:

```
console.log($(this).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5cvgkw6t/2/)

HTML Code -

```
<i class='fas fa-times' style='color: #FFCC00; cursor: pointer;margin-left: 87%; margin-top: -53px; position: absolute;'><input type='hidden' value='123456787' class='notification_trackId'><p style='color: transparent;' class='gsdfs'>Hello World</p></i>
```

JS Code -

```
$(document).on('click', 'i.fas', function(){
    var text = $(this).find(".gsdfs").text();
  console.log(text);
  alert(text);
});
```